# How can I swap two elements in one array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array like :

```
a=np.array([2,7])

a=[2,7]
```

and I want to swap the same array like 7,2 is there anyway to do?

answer should be like 7,2

```
a=[7,2]
```

Comment: `a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#a=np.array([2,7]) 
a=[2,7]

# Reversing a list using slice notation
print (a[::-1]) # [7, 2]

# The reversed() method
print (list(reversed(a))) # [7, 2]
```

swap two elements in a list:

```
# Swap function
def swapPositions(list, pos1, pos2):
    list[pos1], list[pos2] = list[pos2], list[pos1]
    return list


a=[2,7]
pos1, pos2 = 0, 1

print(swapPositions(a, pos1 - 1, pos2 - 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `np.flip(a,0)` See [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) for more information.